# How can you check if a minecraft server has a whitelist enabled, without joining it in the client?

Tags: python-3.x, minecraft

I want to get the info of a minecraft server. I am doing this with Dinnerbones python script, but it doesnt provide any whitelist data. How can I get that ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently **No**.

Per https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus/issues/163 :

> Whether the server is whitelisted or not is not included in the ping or query status data that the servers send. Adding that one field would require going through part of the login process, and is most likely out of the scope of this library.